# Mockup data with phpunit when copying files

Tags: phpunit

I have Class that handle the files function like: copy, move, delete ..etc

Is there a way to copy a file and test it without using copy() method and do not affect on the local files system OS (mac,win...)?  using PHPUnit
I want to use with mockup data, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you [vfsStream](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream) library:

> vfsStream is a PHP stream wrapper for a virtual file system that may
>   be helpful in unit tests to mock the real file system. It can be used
>   with any unit test framework, like PHPUnit or SimpleTest.

Same useful info in:

- [PHPUNIT DOC - Mocking the Filesystem section](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html)
- Really useful code example in this article - [MOCKING THE FILE SYSTEM USING PHPUNIT AND VFSSTREAM](http://tech.vg.no/2011/03/09/mocking-the-file-system-using-phpunit-and-vfsstream/)

Hope this help. Let me know if you need some examples